# Why can't I login my user after registering it?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to authenticate my user's login request but I keep getting "This username is not valid." even though I did register it previously. The only one that can login so far is the admin but I did not create the admin through the registration page.

What's not working and how can I fix it?

These are the serializers:

```
user = get_user_model()

class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   username = serializers.CharField(
       required=True,
       validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all(),lookup='iexact')]
   )

   email = serializers.CharField(
       required=True,
       validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all(),lookup='iexact')]
   )

   password = serializers.CharField(
       required=True,
       label="Password",
       style={'input_type': 'password'}
   )

   password_2 = serializers.CharField(
       required=True,
       label="Confirm Password",
       style={'input_type': 'password'}
   )

   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'password_2',]

   def validate_password(self, value):
       if len(value) < 8:
           raise serializers.ValidationError(
               "Password should be at least 8 characters long.")
       return value

   def validate_password_2(self, value):
       data = self.get_initial()
       password = data.get('password')
       if password != value:
           raise serializers.ValidationError("Passwords don't match.")
       return value

   def validate_username(self, value):
       if User.objects.filter(username=value).exists():
           raise serializers.ValidationError("Username already exists.")
       return value

   def create(self, validated_data):

       user = User.objects.create_user(
           username=validated_data['username'],
           password=validated_data['password'],
           email=validated_data['email']
       )

       return user




class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   username = serializers.CharField(
       required=True,
       write_only=True,
   )

   token = serializers.CharField(
       allow_blank=True,
       read_only=True
   )

   password = serializers.CharField(
       required=True,
       write_only=True,
       style={'input_type': 'password'}
   )

   class Meta(object):
       model = User
       fields = ['username', 'password', 'token']

   def validate(self, data):
       username = data.get('username', None)
       password = data.get('password', None)

       if not username:
           raise serializers.ValidationError("Please enter username to login.")

       user = User.objects.filter( Q(username=username))

       if user.exists() and user.count() == 1:
           user_obj = user.first()
       else:
           raise serializers.ValidationError("This username is not valid.")

       if user_obj:
           if not user_obj.check_password(password):
               raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid credentials.")

       if user_obj.is_active:
           token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user_obj)
           data['token'] = token
       else:
           raise serializers.ValidationError("User not active.")

       return data
```

This is the error in the API view:

```
{
   "non_field_errors": [
       "This username is not valid."
   ]
}
```

These are the views:

```
User = get_user_model()

class UserLoginAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):

   permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
   serializer_class = serializers.UserLoginSerializer
   

   def post(self, request):
       serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
           return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

       return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

   

class UserRegistrationAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):

   permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
   serializer_class = serializers.UserRegistrationSerializer

   def post(self, request):
       serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
           return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

       return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I see that you raise error with this text. Did you check which username you receive and do you have user with this username in database?

Comment: Your error probably comes from the views. Please add them.

Comment: @Dmitry I can see the registered form after I create an user (so I can see the username). The issue is, when I go to the login page and load that data, it says it's not valid but the username was indeed created. I am not sure if maybe the user is not being saved properly or it's something else.

Comment: @Guillaume I added the views now.

Comment: How does you auth work ? How are the tokens created ?

Comment: show us the view handling your login

Comment: @Chymdy The view is there: UserLoginAPIView

Comment: @Guillaume I suppose that must be the problem... I'm new to auth so I didn't know I had to make a separate view/serializer (?) for it, I'll go back to the docs. Thank you.

Comment: That can come from multiple endpoints... how do you send it to your API, have you configured correctly django to handle DRF token or have you created your own auth system... Just a piece of advice, I think the token `get_or_create` shoud take place in the view and not the validation of your serializer since this is logic related. Can't help you much more, you need to investigate the few paths i gave you.